# How I can explain this contradiction?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $A$ be a set such that there exist a bijection (not a group isomorphism) between $G$ and $A$. I know that bijections preserves group structure. However, the set $A$ is not a group. Hence, how I can explain this contradiction?.

Comment: There isn't one; bijections (even between groups) do not in general preserve group structure.

Comment: I think you probably need to present an example of such a bijection that isn't a group isomophism as part of your question; after all, if no such bijection exists then you don't have a contradiction.

Comment: @postmortes In this case $A$ isn't even a group, so there's no chance of a group isomorphism existing. The only requirement is that there exists a set in bijection with $G$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bijection do not preserve group structures. That is the solution to the 'contradiction'. One thing you *can* do with a bijection is *transfer* group (or other algebraic) structures.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "contradiction". Bijection doesn't preserve group structure, a bijective homomorphism does, which is usually called  [Group Isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Given $G$ and $A$ and a bijection $\phi: A \to G$ you can define a group operation on A by setting $ab=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b))$ - so a bijection with a group allows you to give $A$ a group structure, and $A$ with this structure becomes a group.

Given a group $G$ and a set $A$ of the same cardinality, there can be lots of bijections between them. Each bijection transports the group structure in a different way - for example, a different element of the set $A$ may be picked out as the identity.

Where there are different isomorphism classes of groups of the same cardinality - eg the abelian and non-abelian groups of order 6, each can be used to give $A$ a group structure.

A group is often defined as a set equipped with an associative binary operation, an identity and inverses. What is happening here is that you are starting with a set, and using the bijection to give it the necessary elements of the group structure.

Comment: Just a note, this is known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure Moreover, with the structure of group defined on $A$, the map $\phi$ becomes a group ismorphism.